# C#: Why can't I pass 'this' as a constructor argument to a base class?

Tags: c#, constructor

You can't pass `this` as an argument to a base constructor - see e.g., [C# language specification section 10.10.1 Constructor initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645603(v=vs.71).aspx) (last line on page).

I don't understand this limitation and would like to.  In C#, as opposed to C++, the instance being constructed is already at its actual type and "everything works" (though of course not everything is initialized; I mean that virtual functions called in a derived class' constructor execute the derived class' methods).  Base classes are allowed to call virtual methods on themselves even though the derived class' override will be executed and the derived class might not be ready for it; that's not ruled out.  So what is the *reason* for this restriction?

(In C++ this is allowed for three reasons.  First, the user or a derived class is supposed to know what he is doing.  Second, the user of C++ is supposed to know what he is doing. And third, even if the user doesn't know what he is doing the C++ philosophy is to give him the rope he requires to hang himself, and then facilitate him when he ties the knot.  I actually *like* that philosophy!)

What I'm trying to do, by the way, is construct properly initialized list members in a circularly-linked list.  There's a base class `Element` with a field `Link` to point to the next element.  There's a class `Head` which derives from `Element`, it'll be the distinguished sentinel for the start of the list plus have special behavior for the entire list.  The constructor for `Element` takes the head of the list as argument, I want to write as follows to initialize elements and the head properly:

```
class Element {
    protected Element link;
    public Element(Element prior) 
    {
        this.link = null;
        prior.link = this;
    }
};

class Head : Element {
    public Head() : base(this) {}
};
```

(Before you complain that I should do this example differently my actual code is somewhat more complicated - a specialized sparse array - and I have my reasons.)  I'm going to use a factory for Lists (and a factory method on Head for adding elements) to avoid this, which arguably is better design, but I'm puzzled that this other reasonable method is outlawed.

Comment: You are passing a reference to an uninitialized object.  Entirely too many possible accidents, the language forbids it.

Comment: @Hans: It isn't uninitialized: all fields have either their assigned values (due to variable initializers) or default values before the instance constructor is invoked ([section 10.10.3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645606(v=vs.71).aspx)) (and that fact makes it *different* from C++).  The instance may not be *semantically* initialized until the instance constructor finishes running - but *that's* ok when the base class constructor calls virtual methods overridden in the derived class.

Comment: What is the point of arguing about it here?  Talk to the C# language designers.

Comment: @Hans: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to argue.  It thought I made it clear in the question I was asking for a *reason* so I could *understand*.  There are lots of other questions on SO asking for motivations behind the choices made in various languages, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of C# and .NET is intended to give the base class control over its invariants.  Once the base-class constructor has been completed, derived-class code, including derived-class constructors, is allowed to manipulate the base-class portion of the object in any way allowed by the base class.  A derived class cannot do anything with the object under construction other than storing values to its own (derived-type) fields prior to the base-class constructor call, but a base class contract can in effect say "I'm going to call this virtual method during my constructor, and any legitimate derived class must be prepared to deal with that".

The design does pose some limitations.  The worst IMHO is that there is no mechanism by which a base class can assert control of the construction process at any time after the derived-class construction code gets access to its constructor parameters.

C# evaluates field initialization expressions before chaining to the base constructor, on the theory that this will allow derived-class objects to set themselves up before the base constructor calls their virtual methods; a consequence of this is that field-initializer expressions can't do anything with the object under construction.  VB.NET runs initializers after the base constructor, which allows more convenient access but means fields will be unitialized if the base constructor calls any virtual methods.  Personally, I would regard the C# approach as "almost" useful, but the inability to handle classes whose invariants would be affected by constructor parameters severely limits its usefulness.

What I'd really like to see, btw, would be for `Object` to include a virtual method that will run between the time the most derived constructor finishes execution or throws an exception and the time control returns to the code that calls `foo = new Bar();`.  The primary reason that base-class constructors expose the objects under construction before derived-class constructors get to run is that there is no standard way for them to ensure that they'll ever get control after that.  Such a design would greatly improve constructor sequencing.  I'm not holding my breath for such a thing, though.

Comment: You write: "A derived class cannot do anything with the object under construction other than storing values to its own [declared] fields prior to the base-class constructor call..." I assume you are referring only to ***static*** fields here. It would be an important clarification to make in your answer, since the inaccessibility of `this` is exactly the crux of the question.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: Unless things have changed since I wrote the answer (I've not kept up with all the changes to C# or .NET, since my only .NET programming is maintenance of existing projects) I believe it is essentially correct.  Field initializers set *the corresponding fields* of the object under construction, but (unless things have changed) they aren't allowed to form a reference to the object under construction or do anything else with it that would require such a reference.

Comment: Oh I see; you were talking about instance-field initializer code (which personally I rigorously avoid, for unrelated reasons). Originally, by "do anything... prior," I thought you were primarily meaning *from within/at-the time-of a* `: this(...)` *constructor call-site context*, since the latter does indeed seem to satisfy your condition "[not...] prior to the base-class constructor call" (assuming the base class uses `: this(...)` constructor chaining). So my comment is semi-retracted; there's still a minor clarification you could make.